# Определить сколько в строке имеется слов, состоящих из 1, 2, 3 и.т.д. символов

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, node.js

> Определить сколько в строке имеется слов, состоящих из одного, 2, 3 и.т.д. символов

Самое легкое конечно же сделал, но что-то не понимаю как подсчитать кол-во слов.
Можно конечно сделать через if , но получится индусский код,чего не очень бы хотелось.

```js
const str = 'текст тееекст тексты тееекст тееекст'
const word = str.split(' ')
for (const a of word) {
  console.log(a.length)
}
```

Comment: "... состоящих из одного," - из одного чего?

Comment: @Igor исправился

Comment: кол-во слов = word.length

Comment: @Igor Вы не так поняли, смотрите у нас есть строка "один три два три три три" надо вывести что слово "три" вывелось именно 4 раза

Comment: Я не "не так понял", я вообще не понял. Какие "один два три"?

Comment: @Igor смотри, у нас есть строка = "один три два три три три" , мне нужно чтобы программа вывела сколько раз в строке повторяется каждое слово, т.е три повторилось четыре раза, два - один раз, один - один раз.

Comment: Хм, это совершенно не то, что написано в вопросе. Смотрите ответ ниже.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var str =  "один три два три три три";
var words = str.split(" ");
var collect = {};
for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
  // если в словаре еще нет свойства words[i] заводим такое свойство с значением 0
  if (!collect[words[i]])
    collect[words[i]] = 0;
  // увеличиваем счетчик
  collect[words[i]]++;
}

// вывод результатов
for(var word in collect)
  console.log(word, collect[word]);
```

Comment: Спасибо, а можешь объяснить как работает? Для чего нужен восклицательный знак?

Comment: @NyanSoldier добавил комментарии

Comment: почему !collect[words[i]] , для чего там нужен   "!" ?

Comment: @NyanSoldier если у объекта нет свойства с таким названием, обращение к этому свойству возвращает `undefined`, что в булевском представлении соответствует `false`

Comment: @NyanSoldier То есть - если у объекта `collect` нет свойства с названием `words[i]`, заводим такое свойство с значением `0`.

Comment: а если туда попадет 0, то выходит программа сработает с багом? Можно ли сделать через "!==" ?

Comment: @NyanSoldier как туда попадет 0?

Answer (score -1):

Можно попробовать передать через функцию:

```
   function calculateTheWords(message) {

      const splitMessage = message.split(" ");
      const wordsNumber = splitMessage.length;

   return console.log(wordsNumber);
   }

   calculateTheWords("Один два три три два три пять");
```